# wildcard sub domain internal URL rewrite

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, subdomain, internal-dns

I am trying to achieve URL like GitHub Pages. whenever user will visit `username.example.com` internally it will respond from `localhost:80/username`

I am giving some example So that it will make the problem more understandable. 
what I am trying to achieve it

whenever user will visit

```
user1.example.com  -> localhost/user1
user2.example.com  -> localhost/user2

user1.example.com/about  -> localhost/user1/about
user2.example.com/about/somemore  -> localhost/user2/about/somemore
```

I hope my problem is clear to you all.

I am using nginx and I had setup wildcard for the subdomain.

**Currently For any subdomain my website is showing index.html page**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server {
    server_name     ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.example\.com$;

    location / {
            proxy_pass https://example.com/$subdomain$request_uri ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to redirect to some other website.

Comment: I have a node.js (express) webapp where I had wrote code for request url but the problem is that my code see the url parameter after the domain name.

suppose you send a reuest to ```flaixman.example.com``` my code will think that you are trying to vist home page.
but when you will visit ```example.com/flaixman``` then it will show your profile.

Comment: Then this answer should serve you. it makes the rewrites you ask in your question.

Comment: but I don't want that redirect should be visiable to the user browser. It should be done on my Virtual Machine only

Comment: Ooooh okay, then what you want is a proxypass